# React Native: Trying to understand routing logic

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Really new to react native here. Trying to achieve the following app flow:

App launch -> AuthToken check -> ProfileData check -> Main app

For AuthToken check:
- If token exists, append it to headers for future requests
- If no token, redirect to login page, successful login will store token in SecureStore and then append it to headers for future requests

For ProfileData check:
- If no ProfileData, make API request, write to storage, pass to Main app
- If ProfileData exists, retrieve it and pass to Main app

I'm currently using `react-native-router-flux` to load AuthCheck component that basically runs this:

```
    async componentWillMount() {
        await this.tokenCheck();
    }
    async tokenCheck(){
        console.log("Checking for token..");
        let token_exist = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("AuthToken");
        if(!token_exist) {
            Actions.auth();
        }else{
            Actions.main();
        }
    }
```

Where should I place this code if I want to run it on every page? Where do I place the code for retrieving profile details?

Answer (score 0):

Do you even used [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) ?

This is so easy to use and learn , i highly recommend it for you . Also it has very good documentation

This is an easy way to check the authentication in the first and also save the token in AsyncStorage and pass it as props to the other routes :

```
export default mainNavigation = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    Home: HomeStack ,
    SignIn: SignInScreen ,
    Verification: VerificationScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
```

As you can see `AuthScreen` is the initial route

In the `AuthScreen` you have to check the AsyncStorage if a token exist and then validate this token if the token is invalid or not exist, navigate the user to the user to the `SignInScreen` and there you can set a token parameter in AsyncStorage

You should use `createStackNavigator` for HomeScreen to pass the token as the props

Comment: Will check it out, the first tutorial I found used react-native-router-flux so I just stuck to it. Does this allow me to reference the authcheck code on every page without duplicating it?

Comment: @joshua It is better to handle authentication with the server you can send an authorization header and check it access_token on every request

Comment: I am authenticating at the server level, I just want to store the auth token on the local storage so that it persists after app restart